# ALU using modules in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl, digital-logic

I am implementing a 4-bit ALU using Verilog.
I am getting some weird results in testbecnh.

Here is code for the ALU:

```
`include "ripple_carry_adder_4.v"

module alu_4(A, B, CTRL, Y);
    
    input [3:0] A, B;
    input [3:0] CTRL;
    output reg [4:0] Y;
    
    wire [4:0] add;
    wire [4:0] sub;
    
    assign add_ctrl = 1'b0;
    assign sub_ctrl = 1'b1;
    
    ripple_carry_adder_4 rca0(A, B, add_ctrl, add[4:0]);
    ripple_carry_adder_4 rca1(A, B, sub_ctrl, sub[4:0]);
    
    always@(A, B, CTRL)
        begin
            Y = 5'b00000;
            case(CTRL)
                4'b0000 : Y = sub;
                4'b0001 : Y = add;
                default : Y = 5'b0;
            endcase
        end
endmodule
```

Code for above's testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns
`include "alu_4.v"

module alu_4_tb;

reg [3:0] A, B;
reg [3:0] CTRL;
wire [4:0] OUT;

alu_4 a(A, B, CTRL, OUT);

initial
begin

    $dumpfile("alu_4_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, alu_4_tb);
    
    CTRL=4'b0000;
    A=$random;
    B=$random;
    #40;
    
    CTRL=4'b0001;
    A=$random;
    B=$random;
    #40;

    
    $display("Test completed");

end

endmodule
```

Code for ripple adder

```
module ripple_carry_adder_4(A, B, CTRL, S);

    input [3:0] A, B;
    input CTRL;
    output [4:0] S;
    wire w[2:0];
    wire o[3:0];
    
    xor_2 x0(B[0], CTRL, o[0]);
    xor_2 x1(B[1], CTRL, o[1]);
    xor_2 x2(B[2], CTRL, o[2]);
    xor_2 x3(B[3], CTRL, o[3]);
    
    assign Cin = CTRL | 0;
    
    full_adder f0(A[0], o[0], Cin, S[0], w[0]);
    full_adder f1(A[1], o[1], w[0], S[1], w[1]);
    full_adder f2(A[2], o[2], w[1], S[2], w[2]);
    full_adder f3(A[3], o[3], w[2], S[3], S[4]);
    
endmodule
```

I individually tested the ripple adder and there are no problems.
Incase of ALU, I observe that the the answer during subtractions always has a '1' ahead of the correct answer. For example, 9-3 = 6. But the answer produced is 16.
Another is a case of 4-1 which should be 3, but the answer stored is 13.
I have attached the testbench sims below. Kindly help.

Also, no matter how I change the order of simulation, the first operation is always producing unknown('x') state in Y. The wire **add** & **sub** are storing the results correctly, but when I transfer those results to **Y**, it's all going wrong. It's a basic reg=wire statement.
[image]

[image]

Code for full adder

```
`include "xor_2.v"

module full_adder(A, B, Cin, S, Cout);

    input A, B, Cin;
    output S, Cout;
    wire w1;
    
    assign Cout = (A & Cin) | (B & Cin) | (A & B);
    
xor_2 x1(A, B, w1);
xor_2 x2(w1, Cin, S);

endmodule
```

Code for XOR

```
module xor_2(A, B, C);

    input A, B;
    output C;
    
    assign C = A&(~B) | (~A)&B;
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an incomplete sensitivity list.  Change:

```
    always@(A, B, CTRL)
```

to:

```
    always @*
```

This removes the `x` at the beginning of the simulation.  Your code ignores changes on `sub` and `add` because those signals are not in the sensitivity list.  Refer to IEEE Std, section 9.4.2.2 *Implicit event_expression list*.

---

> I individually tested the ripple adder, and there are no problems.

This claim is incorrect, as this trivial testbench of the `ripple_carry_adder_4` demonstrates:

```
module tb;
    reg [3:0] A=9;
    reg [3:0] B=3;
    reg CTRL=1;
    wire [4:0] S;

ripple_carry_adder_4 dut (
    .A     (A),
    .B     (B),
    .CTRL  (CTRL),
    .S     (S)
);

initial begin
    $monitorh("S=", S);
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

The output is:

```
S=16
```

You need to debug your design further.  Perhaps you have a connection error.